# JDK11 + NetBeans 8.2 - cannot access java.lang

Tags: netbeans-8, java-11

For a project I'm working on, I need to use JDK11 (group project, working with JPA and JavaFX). I'm using NetBeans 8.2, but I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot access java.lang
  Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

I have tried re-installing JDK11, which doesn't work. The strange thing is, the classpath is empty whereas for my fellow students this was filled in automatically. I also had to manually fill in the location of the source, whereas the other people didn't.

[image]

[image]

In my project.properties I have the following processorpath:

```
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 does not support Java 11, you need to upgrade to NetBeans 10

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. Thank you.